# Player Follow Camera Goes Inside Objects

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was working on a 3d game where the camera is continuously following the player object in position and rotation fields.

Complete 3d environment is set up as per my gameplay. A player moves and rotates in different areas of the environment, I was getting this kind of abnormal view in front of the screen. The camera goes into the other objects.

[image]

This is a really poor gameplay experience so how to fix this? 
How to make this look better when the player following the camera goes inside other environment objects?

Answer (score 1):

You can make an empty gameobject inside the player, then your camera script should not follow the player, but it should follow the empty gameobject instead. 
if you define an offset, it would be best practice
camera script is as below:

```
public class Followplayer : MonoBehaviour {

     public Transform player;
    public Vector3 offset;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        transform.position = player.position + offset;
    }
}
```